# Как добавлять и удалять класс по клику (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

.toggle() вырезали в 1.9, но сейчас не много по другому он работает. Я еще не доучил чистый js и только знакомлюсь с jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".example").toggleClass("bounce")
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

На javascript

```js
var elementButton = document.querySelector('button'),
    elementSquare = document.querySelector('.square');

elementButton.onclick = function() {
    elementSquare.classList.toggle('circle');
}
```

```css
body{
  padding-top: 45px;
}
.square {
    margin: 25px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    transition: .3s;
}

.circle {    
    border-radius: 50%;
}

button{
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>

<div class="square"></div>
```